# Search does not support accute accent

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I always wondered why I could not find jobs in [Montreal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montreal).

If I look for "Montreal", I get [0 results](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=montreal&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles).

If I look for "Montréal", I get [16 results](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=montr%C3%A9al&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles).

I think the search box should simply ignore accute accent when comparing the query with results.

Comment: This is obviously a limitation of the SE search.  It is not very flexible when it comes to variations in exact string searches `Montreal <> Montréal` but it should be from a search perspective because if I don't have French or Spanish keys on my keyboard, it requires 3 or 4 extra steps to add those characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We already do support typing in location names with and without accent characters. In this case, we had simply cached "Montreal" as Montreal, Wisconsin (which is, indeed, spelled without the accent), so it was showing you results there (which there are none).

Since virtually anyone typing in "Montreal" is intending Montreal, QC, Canada, I've removed that cached value. You'll notice the results are now the same for both searches. Thanks for the report.